# Windows media app works strange for me HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, windows, windows-media-player

I've a Windows Media Player box on me page, but... 
The Windows Media Player will overlap every peace of html code how can I get it to the back and that I can still use it? And my second problem is that everybody that visit my page needed a plugin for loading it, but veryone has Windows Media Player installed on his PC? Who can help me and explain something :< Thanks already :D

```
<object id='mediaplayer' classid='clsid:6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6' type='application/x-oleobject' width='100%' height='150px'>
 <param name='url' value='SONG.mp3'/>
 <param name='autostart' value='1'/>
 <param name='showcontrols' value='1'/>
 <param name='stretchtofit' value='0'/>
 <param name='enablecontextmenu' value='0'/>
 <param name='ShowStatusBar' value='1'>
 <embed src='SONG.mp3' width='100%' height='150px' autostart='1' type='application/x-  
 mplayer2' pluginspage='http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/' 
 transparentatstart='0' animationatstart='0' showcontrols='1' autosize='0' displaysize='0'
 showtracker='0' ShowStatusBar='1'></embed>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question is difficult to answer without some sample code to work with.
I would recommend added a presized container div to hold the player in your desired location on the page.

**To answer the senond part of your question.**

Embedding media player in your webpage means users will be executing the file through their web browser. A plugin for the users specific browser is required to play back the files.

This is standalone from windows media player and will allow users who do not have media player to play the files from their desired browser and operating system.

If you want people to use there installed media player then a link to download the file and execute it on their own computer is required.